# How can I sign tweets containing my custom "via" with the iOS 5 Twitter framework?

Tags: ios, twitter, twrequest

As you probably know Apple released a Twitter framework with iOS 5. It provides a class called
`TWRequest` which allows you to make HTTP calls to the Twitter API. The `accountsd` process takes care of all the OAuth signing. 
If you make such a `TWRequest` your tweets shows up as "via iOS". Is there a way to embed my client specific information to don't lose this identification?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't actually set this.

According to: https://dev.twitter.com/issues/39
They match based on the app name in Apple's database.  You can't already have a registered Twitter Application with the same name.

Also, seems that you can't get this to work with AdHocs or test apps, only published apps.

Comment: How are we expected to have backwards compatibility that has both 'via myapp' for both iOS5 tweets and other framework tweets? Also, what's to stop someone from registering an app on twitter that has the same name as our iphone apps, thus breaking the 'via appname' feature. This seems unscrupulously thought out.

Comment: I agree, it feels completely broken.  I just released an iPad app today (check it out http://bit.ly/PartyDoodles ) and it's using the iOS5 Twitter integration.  Now it's published, and it still reports all tweets as coming from iOS.  I'm going to use a support request to try and get more info on how we can fix it and support iOS 4 still.  If I get any answers I'll post the info.

Comment: Thanks dave that'd be great, I'm releasing a game shortly, Universal too (what a nightmare in itself! haha) but just adding social media stuff in, I'm opting to currently not use the iOS 5 twitter support and make all devices use MGTwitterengine (thanks matt if your reading!)